# C++ How do you initialize a long double?

Tags: c++, mingw

I try to initialize a long double with the following:

```
using namespace std;

int main(){

    long double initial = 0.9999952L;

    cout << initial << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But I get the following output:

```
C:\MinGW\bin>a.exe
-1.#QNAN
```

What is the appropriate way to intialize a long double?

Comment: Seems ok to me. Works fine too. https://ideone.com/4I3kyf.

Comment: Could this be the version of the compiler i'm using, such as 32-bit vs 64-bit or something

Comment: @JoeBass what compiler, compiler version, and OS are you using?

Comment: @DaichiJameson Windows 10, ../src/gcc-5.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32

Comment: maybe this is a windows platform issue? MSVC doesn't support "real" `long double`. Maybe mingw uses a 10-byte `long double`, while the C library uses a 8-byte one.

Comment: @geza sizeof(long double) returns 12

Comment: @JoeBass: that means that mingw uses 10-byte `long double`s (it is just aligned to 4-byte, so it becomes 12-byte sized). The question is, how `cout` works. If it boils down to some MSVCRT.dll or LIBCMT from MSVC, then it is very likely that this issue is what I've said previously. Maybe mingw has a switch that it should use the GNU standard library?

Comment: MinGW has a well known problem with type `long double`. The compiler, gcc, uses one representation for `long double`; the runtime library, from Microsoft, uses a different representation. (Neither is incorrect; the bug is in the way they're integrated into the MinGW implementation.) I'll mark this as a duplicate when I find an appropriate question that deals with it specifically.

Comment: The initialization is correct. The problem is in printing it. My answer to the duplicate question provides a workaround, `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`, that will likely work for C++ as well as for C.

Comment: @KeithThompson yes that was it